# How to draw a triangle shape attached to a Rectangle?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-vectordrawable

I am newbie in designing vector drawables in android.

I would like to design like following but not sure how to accomplish this

[image]

I have tried the following code snippet

```
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-45"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toDegrees="-45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#fffff" />

            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/dim_200dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/dim_50dp"
                android:topRightRadius="@dimen/dim_50dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/dim_50dp"></corners>
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

But I got only the following result

[image]

Please help me get the solution

Comment: instead of drawable, create an svg.

Comment: use the vector drawables, https://dev.to/brightdevs/creating-simple-vector-drawables-in-android-studio-bbm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some 9-patch images matching your need. Using this drawable you can place each one as you wish on the screen according to your case:

**triangle_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="90dp"
        android:height="160dp"
        android:bottom="137dp">
        <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/top_bg"/>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="90dp"
        android:height="60dp"
        android:top="137dp">
        <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/bottom_bg"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You can download drawables [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iy6fqzykgka1w7u/drawables.zip?dl=0). The original PSD file used to build 9-patches is also available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5jak7nhy9f9fqq/bg.psd?dl=0).

The final output would look like this:
[image: Preview]

Hope it helps.

Comment: It shows “ Your requested URL has been blocked as per the directions received from Department of Telecommunications, Government of India ”

Comment: I have updated the links, check my updated answer. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: I have tried but somewhat not matching with the expected result. Please check the screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/nh4qmrrdmwdpcsl/layout-2019-07-09-052156.png?dl=0

Comment: Try to change height (160 and 60dp in my example) and top and bottom inset (137dp) in the xml drawable to match your case.

Comment: Thanks for your great help :-)